# importing MYSQL database from one server to new server

Tags: php, mysql, database, import, phpmyadmin

I just completed our website's new DB Design. In the new Database there are few columns renamed, few tables added and few columns inside it added. Now after importing contents of the existing DB( with 10k+ Rows ) to New Database and opening the home.php file, The server takes infinite time to load and Hangs, and when it loads the posts don't show up (Keeps on loading)! I checked twice there is no error in the code and everything is working fine when that database is used from Localhost. 
Older Database Query in home.php was only 1 SELECT Statement.
But now In Home.php There is ajax request which is executing a 3 Loop Query.

```
$net = "SELECT idpost FROM p_n_relation WHERE `idnetwork` IN (SELECT idnetwork FROM u_n_relation WHERE iduser = '$iduser' AND isActive = 1 AND isDeleted = 0) AND isActive = 1 AND isDeleted = 0";
```

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM emotions WHERE ( randomid IN (".$net.") AND isActive = 1
AND isDeleted = 0 AND onid = '0' AND type = 0 )ORDER BY rating DESC
LIMIT ".$cp.",".$n
```

Is it possible that this query became too heavy and is not taking time with less data but taking so much time with 10k+. 
In u_n_ relation there are 3k, in p_n_relation there are 10k and emotions 10k rows.
We are using 1GB RAM , Single core Digital ocean Server.
PS - Rest all static pages are loading.
Please have a look yourself : http://128.199.77.57 
username : guest 
password : guestisepic

Comment: That's not really enough detail to answer the question.  In general, I would suggest avoiding subselects in MySQL -- the subquery tends to get executed for each candidate row, which means that your query starts to look like an O(n^n) operation.  What's worse, is you have a subselect inside a subselect, which means O(n^(n^n))!

Comment: You could use XDebug to find out exactly where the code hangs.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the two table structures.  Especially check that the KEY is correct.  Did you rename a column that is in the Index?

Export the structures of both table in phpMyAdmin.